# want to run the python script (runp.py) after 15 seconds

Tags: python

I want to run the python script (runp.py) after 15 seconds.
What is wrong with the following code?

```
import time, subprocess
time.sleep(15)
python = 'C:\\Python32\\python.exe'
runp = 'C:\\Users\\viena\\Desktop\\runp.py'
subprocess.call([python,runp])
```

The runp.py includes only the following code:

```
print ('asdf')
```

however, I could not get the result on screen.

Comment: What actually happens? What's visibly wrong when you try to run it?

Comment: "I could not get the result on screen" - what actually happened? After you waited 15 seconds, did you get an error message? Did the program keep running without doing anything? Did the window close? Did you get dumped back to the command prompt?

Comment: @user2357112 the program keep running without doing anything, finally the command prompt screen just blink and goes out, but no result displayed

Comment: "blink and goes out" - do you mean it closes? How are you running this program? Are you double-clicking the file? Try running it from a command prompt.

Comment: From the Python Docs: "The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system."   In Java you need to catch the exception and sleep the thread again, i.e: `try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}`

Answer (score 3):

Your code running fine (at least for me) but command prompt is not waiting anything to close so it appears and closes in a blink of an eye. 
To make it stay in there, adding `raw_input()` is one way. For python 3.xx it is `input()`

or

```
import os
os.system("pause")
```

**EDIT:**  Add one of those to end of your `runp.py`